# How do I deal with non-matching units in 2D dynamical systems?

Tags: linear-algebra, dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes, gradient-flows

I am formulating a set of relationships between two variables, x and y. Both variables represent real world quantities, and have associated units. These units are not the same for x and for y.

My plan was to formulate a model linear (gradient) system, with a quadric potential $V(x,y)$:
$$
-\frac{\partial V}{\partial x} = \frac{dx}{dt} = ax + by\\
-\frac{\partial V}{\partial y} = \frac{dy}{dt} = cx + dy
$$

I believe for the potential $V$ to be well-defined, I need to require that $b=c$ (requirement for a gradient system I think?).

I am immediately confused because of the units of $b$. Using square brackets to denote, "units of", does $b$ have units of $[\frac{x}{y\cdot t}]$ as in the first equation or units of $[\frac{y}{x\cdot t}]$ as in the second?

Is this something fundamental about potential fields / gradient systems, that the variables must have the same units?

Comment: One obvious way around this is to start not with $x,y$ themselves but dimensionless variables $X:=x/x_0$, $Y:=y/y_0$ are appropriate reference values.

Comment: Why would it matter?  The units are absorbed already in the constants that you choose, similar to the $k$ and $m$ in the example of simple harmonic oscillator $V(x,\dot{x})=\frac12 mx^2+\frac12k\dot{x}^2$, to make it dimensionless in the end.  $\mathbb{R}^n$ does not come with "unit"s.

Comment: @Semiclassical: I agree rescaling makes sense (although the rescaling values are not evident in my case). The issue I don't get is that for the system to be a gradient system requires $b=c$, but re-scaling changes the coefficients (constant matrix). If, say, I change variables using $u=x/x_0$, then the system becomes $du/dt = au+by/x_0$ and $dy/dt = b x_0 u+dy$. The eigenvalues are unchanged, but since the mixed partials are no longer equal it is no longer a gradient system. It looks like there is always one scaling that leads to a gradient system. This seems important, but I'm not seeing why.

Comment: It'll be a gradient system in the variables $X,Y$. That doesn't seem so strange to me.